# cannot access deep nested objects in fetch response in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, openweathermap

So i stumbled across a lot of examples on Stack and the web, where accessing deep nested objects from a async fetch call return undefined. A lot of answers are resolved to other articles resulting in the way objects and arrays are accessed. Others claim that it's the reason of async operations. I just can't really get my head around it though.

this is the data:

```js
base: "stations"
clouds: {all: 1}
cod: 200
coord: {lon: -81.38, lat: 28.54}
dt: 1607561322
id: 4167147
main: {temp: 51.28, feels_like: 45.97, temp_min: 48.99, temp_max: 53.6, pressure: 1021, …}
name: "Orlando"
sys: {type: 1, id: 5234, country: "US", sunrise: 1607515628, sunset: 1607552963}
timezone: -18000
visibility: 10000
weather: [{…}]
wind: {speed: 4.52, deg: 271}
```

this is the code, notice the setWeatherData in the useEffect callback

```js
function WeatherDisplay(props){
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Orlando&units=imperial&appid=3abd9c2df6a249e8abcf4f812de0a627`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      setWeatherData({
        data,
        name: data.name,
        main: data.main,
        ...data.main
      })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }, [])


  return(
    <>
      <Media style={{backgroundColor: "gray", borderRadius: "5px", height: "5.5rem"}}>
        <IconContext.Provider value={{size: "5rem", style:{fontWeight: "200"}, className:"align-self-center"}}>
          <TiWeatherPartlySunny />
        </IconContext.Provider>
          {console.log(weatherData)}
          {console.log(weatherData.name)}
          {console.log(weatherData.main)}
          {console.log(weatherData.temp)}
      </Media>
    </>
  )
}
```

[image: this is the console.log]

this is how is started
first I just setWeatherData to data, for that I could render weatherData.name (Orlando) but for some reason weatherData.main.temp came back with an error because weatherData.main results in undefined. I asked around and they say it's because promises and it's async, so I have to use a conditional blah blah, but that still doesn't explain how it was able to access weatherData.name. It's the same with weatherData.clouds and .sys

I went ahead and just spread the values of the object I wanted, but I can think of easy situations where my workaround won't be useful.

I wondered if it was the way react saved the value of a deeply nested object, but I don't really know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah this is because of asynchronous behavior. The `weatherData` object will always exist (as {} initially, then with the fetched data once the request finishes).

In the initial render, `weatherData.name` will equal `{}.name` which will return undefined, but will not cause an error.

However when you run `weatherData.main.temp` it will equal `{}.main.temp`, meaning you are effectively calling `undefined.temp` which will throw an error. This error will only be throwed as long as the `main` prop is undefined, meaning it should work correctly once the data is actually fetched.

You can solve this in a few different ways, I recommend one of the following two:

1. A conditional render that renders a "loading data..." etc if the fetch has not been completed.
2. Conditional accessors. Try accessing `weatherData.main?.temp` instead of `weatherData.main.temp`. Not sure if it will work inside JSX, but it should work outside assuming you are using a recent version of babel that will transpile conditional branching correctly.
3. You could also create an initial `weatherData` object with the expected interface defined, but all the values set to `undefined`.

In other words,

```
const initialWeatherData = {
  name: undefined,
  main: {
    temp: undefined,
  }
}
// etc, leaving out most of the object as I'm sure you get what I'm trying to do
// just make sure you define the entire interface

const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState(initalWeatherData);
```

Comment: {}.name did not return undefined, it returned "Orlando" as you can easily see in the console.log picture.

Comment: Did it not return `undefined` on the intial render? There should be four `undefined` further up in the console log. Then on the second render you get the output that you pasted in your question.

Comment: I see, so how is it on the second render it returns .name but .main is still undefined? Do I need to wait for certain keys to be fetched also? How come the whole object let me access one property but not the other?

Comment: Nah the entire object should be set once you get the response. It looks especially strange as it seems you can access the `.main` props just fine after it's spread with `weatherData.temp`. I honestly have no idea why that wouldn't work @_@

Comment: Exactly, I was just making sure it wasnt some rookie mistake I was making. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Ok so I just tested doing something similar (without React rendering, just fetching and assigning like you do, then outputting). It works just fine, as expected, so I couldn't reproduce your bug. So I really have no idea. Is the code in your codebase identical to the one you posted here?

Comment: ahh I got it. Yea the reason why it didn't work is because in the first render threw an error before getting to the second render. Thanks

Comment: The "?" works for me perfectly. Thanks. I'm gonna search for what that symbol means in JS.

Comment: @ChristianErick Great to hear something worked out! The `?.` syntax is called Optional chaining. You can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 1):

If you set as below

```js
setWeatherData({
    data
})
```

Your weather data will be

```js
{
    data: {
        main: {...},
        name: '...'
        sys: {...}
    }
}
```

To access main, you should use

```js
weatherData.data.main
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, your issue is you called an API successfully but found in the API result that main field is undefined, while name and sys and clouds fields are not empty. If yes, you should handle the case when an API return empty and try to call it again until you get the value. If no, could you show us what error you get?

Comment: all the field are there. None of them are null or empty. However, I could only access/render the name field. In the then callback of the fetch call. I could easily access any field, just not in the render.

Answer (score 0):

You take the idea with this code and API image. Hope it will helpful for you

[image]

```
import React  from 'react'

class GetData extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: []

    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const url = "http://localhost:8000/blogList";
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({ data: data.result });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);

        }
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state

        return (

            <div>{
                <ul>
                    {data.map((item, i) => {
                        return <li key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>

                    })}
                </ul>

            }
            </div>


        );
    }
}
export default GetData
```